# How would I store the health values and run again until either player health == 0 or enemy health == 0

Tags: java, eclipse

What would be the best way for me to code the the actual attack / defend between the two characters and how would I store the health value so that re attacks could be stored until either player health or enemy health reached 0, and then declare the victor. This is my first ever attempt at any kind programming after self teaching from various sources, please also give me feed back on any improvement I could make, I'm sure there will be many.

Thank you in advance.

:-)

```
package test;

public class BattleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerStats ps = new PlayerStats();
        EnemyStats es = new EnemyStats();
        int eh = es.getEnemyHealth();
        int ph = ps.getPlayerHealth();

        ps.PlayerAttackDefend();
        es.AttackDefend();

        System.out.println("You chose to " + ps.getpInput() + " and rolled "
                + ps.getPlayerRoll());

        System.out.println("The enemy chose to " + es.getEaod()
                + " and rolled " + es.getEnemyRoll() + ".");

        if (ps.getpInput().equals("Attack")) {

            if (es.getEaod().equals("Attack")) {

                System.out
                        .println("YOUR SWORDS BOUNCE OFF EACHOUTHERS... TRY AGAIN!");
                System.exit(0);

            }

            if (es.getEaod().equals("Defend")) {

                if (ps.getPlayerRoll() > es.getEnemyRoll())

                    eh -= ps.getPlayerRoll() - es.getEnemyRoll();

                System.out.println("Enemy Health is " + eh);
            }
        }

        if (ps.getpInput().equals("Defend")) {

            if (es.getEaod().equals("Defend")) {

                System.out
                        .println("YOUR SHIELDS BOUNCE OFF EACHOTHERS... TRY AGAIN!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        if (es.getEaod().equals("Attack")) {

            if (es.getEnemyRoll() > ps.getPlayerRoll())

                ph -= es.getEnemyRoll() - ps.getPlayerRoll();

            System.out.println("Your Health is " + ph);

        }
    }
}
```

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayerStats {

    static Scanner paod = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Players initial health value.

    private int playerHealth = 10;

    //RNG for attack value / defence value using dice as object.

    private int playerRoll = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    private String pInput;

    //Method for selecting Attack or Defence.

    public void PlayerAttackDefend() {

        System.out.println("Do you want to Attack or Defend?");
        System.out.println("a = Attack  / d = Defend");

        //Player selects attack or defend.

        String userInput = paod.nextLine();
        if (userInput.equals("a")) {
            pInput = "Attack";
        }

        if (userInput.equals("d")) {
            pInput = "Defend";

        }
    }

    public static Scanner getPaod() {
        return paod;
    }


    public int getPlayerHealth() {
        return playerHealth;
    }


    public int getPlayerRoll() {
        return playerRoll;
    }


    public String getpInput() {
        return pInput;
    }


    public static void setPaod(Scanner paod) {
        PlayerStats.paod = paod;
    }


    public void setPlayerHealth(int playerHealth) {
        this.playerHealth = playerHealth;
    }


    public void setPlayerRoll(int playerRoll) {
        this.playerRoll = playerRoll;
    }


    public void setpInput(String pInput) {
        this.pInput = pInput;
    }
}
```

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;

public class EnemyStats {

    //Enemy initial health value.

    private int enemyHealth = 10;

    //RNG for attack value / defence value using dice as object.

    private static int enemyRoll = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;

    //RNG for enemy decision to Attack or Defend.

    private static int eAttackDefend = new Random().nextInt(2) + 1;

    //Used for returning attack or defend string.

    private static String eaod;

    //Attack or Defend method.

    public void AttackDefend() {

        if (eAttackDefend == 1) {
            eaod = "Attack";

        } else {

            eaod = "Defend";
        }
    }

    public int getEnemyHealth() {
        return enemyHealth;
    }

    public int getEnemyRoll() {
        return enemyRoll;
    }

    public int geteAttackDefend() {
        return eAttackDefend;
    }

    public String getEaod() {
        return eaod;
    }

    public void setEnemyHealth(int enemyHealth) {
        this.enemyHealth = enemyHealth;
    }

    public void setEnemyRoll(int enemyRoll) {
        EnemyStats.enemyRoll = enemyRoll;
    }

    public void seteAttackDefend(int eAttackDefend) {
        EnemyStats.eAttackDefend = eAttackDefend;
    }

    public void setEaod(String eaod) {
        EnemyStats.eaod = eaod;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would to be to set maxHp and actualHp values, if you want to be able to "heal".
If you just decrease until one is dead, you can just decrease the actual health variable you already have.

You might wanna take a look at Inheritance in general, as you have a lot of duplicate code.

In general, just make a loop

```
while(ps.getHealth() > 0 && es.getHealth() > 0) {
  // your battle code
}
```

you might want to remove the `System.exit(0)` calls, as they terminate the program.

Add to the player/enemy a `dealDamage(int damage)` method to actually be able to reduce their health
The health values should be in the objects, and you should not need to store them in your BattleClass.

Comment: Ah thank you. that makes so much sense. I will get on to it now. Don't know why I didn't think of it like that. I'll get there hopefully.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I could give you the short answer but I guess you get more out of a detailed explanation :-)

You want to run your code "until either player health or enemy health reached 0" so you need a loop.

In java you have 3 kinds of loops:

**The for loop**

```
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++) System.out.println("Hello Musketeer Nr. "+i);
```

The most elaborate loop, the for loop consists of three parts, the initialization, the condition, and the afterthought. While the for loop can be used differently, it is mostly is used in the fashion shown here, that is, you have a counter variable whose value you need somehow.

If you don't need the counter variable value, you can use the short form with collections and arrays:

```
for(Person p: persons) System.out.println("Hello, "+person.getName()+"!");
```

**The while loop**
The second most commonly used (at least by me) loop, it has an initial condition and iterates, as long as it is true.

```
while(ph>0&&eh>0)
{
 ...
}
```

As you see, it fits your problem very well. For completeness, I will however describe the third loop which is the

**do-while loop**

```
do
{
 ...
}
while(ph>0&&eh>0)
```

You use this loop like the while loop but if you want to have at least one run through.

**Other Remarks**

Why have two classes PlayerStats and EnemyStats in combat system (they both seem to have the same actions and values) ? You could just have:

```
Stats playerStats=new Stats();
Stats enemyStats=new Stats();
```

Comment: wow thank you. good point with the stats classes, will look into that also.